# Possible to add array to my create method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to create a new record for my `Account` model.

My model has the following structure: `'title','information','image','combat','quest','price'`
I also have 24 more items on my model that are considered as `skills`

I want to make it possible that for those 24 items I can make a loop in my create method, so that I don't have to manually add all the skills in my create.

**Model looks like the following:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image_url');
        $table->integer('quest_points');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('information');
        $table->integer('attack');
        $table->integer('defence');
        $table->integer('strength');
        $table->integer('constitution');
        $table->integer('cooking');
        $table->integer('construction');
        $table->integer('farming');
        $table->integer('crafting');
        $table->integer('firemaking');
        $table->integer('fishing');
        $table->integer('fletching');
        $table->integer('herblore');
        $table->integer('hunter');
        $table->integer('magic');
        $table->integer('mining');
        $table->integer('prayer');
        $table->integer('ranged');
        $table->integer('runecrafting');
        $table->integer('slayer');
        $table->integer('smithing');
        $table->integer('agility');
        $table->integer('thieving');
        $table->integer('woodcutting');
        $table->integer('total_level');
        $table->integer('combat_level');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**My create method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $account = $request->all('title','description','image','combat','quest','price');
    $skills = $request->get('skill');

    // array of 24 items, example -> 'attack' = 52;  

    Account::create([
        'title' => $account['title'],
        'price' => $account['price'],
        'information' => $account['description'],
        'image_url' => $account['image'],
        'combat_level' => $account['combat'],
        'quest_points' => $account['quest'],

        // I would do the following normally

        'attack' => $skills['attack'],
        'defence' => $skills['defence'],

        // ....
        // possible to do this with a loop of the array $skills? 

    ]);

}
```

Comment: Better use the skill names as value in a separate `skill` table instead of as column name in `account` table and use `foreign_key` to make relationship between these 2 tables.

Comment: I do have a skill table, so making a relationship would be a good thing, but I would still need to make some kind of loop in the create method

Comment: `array_merge` skills & account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the same names to the input fields as table columns after that you can create record using the following. It should work

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($account, $skills);
Account::create($mergedArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

First make sure the name of the input fields is the same name as table records after that you can create record using the following:

```
Account::create($skills);
```

And If you want to insert many skills into account model you can use `insert` method

```
$skills = array(
    $array_of_skills,
    $array_of_skills_,
    //...
);

Account::insert($skills);
```